# How to pass a parameter to login view in django while reversing from login url in settings.py?

Tags: python, django, bitnami

I'm having the following issue:
 I have an app that requires a parameter to be passed at login so the url structure is like this -> http://baseURL.com/paramter/

where "parameter" is a variable that is matched later on from a database.

The project is working just fine except when the following scenario occurs:
http://baseURL.com/paramter/home

where "home" is a view that requires the user to be logged in by @login_required 
so the project checks the login_url in settings.py file and tries to go there 
and then I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /parameter/home/

Reverse for 'login_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

## In my settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login_view')
```

## In my views.py

```
def login_view(request, parameter):
```

## In urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<parameter>\w+)/$', 'myproject.apps.myapp.views.login_view'),
```

So how to pass that parameter if settings.py goes to the login view before the url config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pass arguments to the reverse function as `kwargs`

```
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login_view', kwargs={'parameter': 'login_parameter'})
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Usually the login url does not belong into `settings.py`. You just put it into your `urls.py`

Comment: The problem is how to get the login_parameter which gets typed in the url

Comment: I am not sure, I get it right: If you want to access the parameter, it is in your view in the parameter variable

Comment: after trying what you suggested it redirects to this: http://myURL.com/accounts/login/?next=/login_paramter/home/   so how can I get rid of accounts/login to be /login_paramter/ with the next part only for home

Comment: `login_parameter` is a string. You can put any function there to calculate your login parameter. e.g.
`reverse_lazy('login_view', kwargs={'parameter': calculate_parameter()})`